# Plotly python ssl authentification error

Tags: python, pandas, ssl-certificate, dataframe, plotly

I'm using ipython notebook with Anaconda and I'm trying to plot data from a pandas dataframe using plotly. Before plotting, I make sure to set my credentials as shown:

```
plotly_username = "username"
plotly_api_key = "password"
```

However, I get this error:

> [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed
>   (_ssl.c:581)

I followed the tutorials and set up a plotly account, went to https://plot.ly/settings/api and copied and pasted my username and key. Am I doing something wrong? I'm really not sure why I'm getting this error?

EDIT:code

```
import plotly
import plotly.plotly as p
def df_to_iplot(df):

'''
Coverting a Pandas Data Frame to Plotly interface
'''

if df.index.__class__.__name__=="DatetimeIndex":
    #Convert the index to MySQL Datetime like strings
    x=df.index.format()
    #Alternatively, directly use x, since DateTime index is np.datetime64
    #see http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/cparmer/7721116  
    #x=df.index.values.astype('datetime64[s]')
else:
    x = df.index.values        

lines={}
for key in df:
    lines[key]={}
    lines[key]["x"]=x
    lines[key]["y"]=df[key].values
    lines[key]["name"]=key

#Appending all lines
lines_plotly=[lines[key] for key in df]
return lines_plotly
```

then I call:

```
plotly.tools.set_credentials_file(username=plotly_username, api_key=plotly_api_key)  
p.iplot(df_to_iplot(df))
```

ERROR:

```
SSLError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-5ac4417b1800> in <module>()
----> 4 p.plot(df_to_iplot(vehicle_df))

C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\plotly\plotly\plotly.pyc in plot(figure_or_data, validate, **plot_options)
    189                 pass
    190     plot_options = _plot_option_logic(plot_options)
--> 191     res = _send_to_plotly(figure, **plot_options)
    192     if res['error'] == '':
    193         if plot_options['auto_open']:

C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\plotly\plotly\plotly.pyc in _send_to_plotly(figure, **plot_options)
   1253 
   1254     r = requests.post(url, data=payload,
-> 1255                       verify=get_config()['plotly_ssl_verification'])
   1256     r.raise_for_status()
   1257     r = json.loads(r.text)

C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\requests\api.pyc in post(url, data, json, **kwargs)
    107     """
    108 
--> 109     return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
    110 
    111 

C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\requests\api.pyc in request(method, url, **kwargs)
     48 
     49     session = sessions.Session()
---> 50     response = session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
     51     # By explicitly closing the session, we avoid leaving sockets open which
     52     # can trigger a ResourceWarning in some cases, and look like a memory leak

C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.pyc in request(self, method, url, params, data, headers, cookies, files, auth, timeout, allow_redirects, proxies, hooks, stream, verify, cert, json)
    463         }
    464         send_kwargs.update(settings)
--> 465         resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
    466 
    467         return resp

C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.pyc in send(self, request, **kwargs)
    571 
    572         # Send the request
--> 573         r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
    574 
    575         # Total elapsed time of the request (approximately)

C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.pyc in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    429         except (_SSLError, _HTTPError) as e:
    430             if isinstance(e, _SSLError):
--> 431                 raise SSLError(e, request=request)
    432             elif isinstance(e, ReadTimeoutError):
    433                 raise ReadTimeout(e, request=request)

SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:581)
```

Comment: Show us the full error and the relevant code (the one that makes queries to plotly). Credentials are irrelevant as far as SSL verification is concerned.

Comment: By full error I meant you should include the stacktrace (which is the output lines leading up to what you pasted). It starts with "Traceback..."